# Open File dialog box for Excel

Tags: c#, excel, windows-forms-designer

I am currently using Microsoft.Office.Core; and using Excel (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) to export my data from a Windows form to Excel.

When I export my file it always gets overwritten. I heard we can use the "Open File" dialog box to save the file in the location we want.

I had also included the way i exported the data to excel here

Does anyone know of a way to solve it?

```
            chart1.SaveImage("C:\\New folder\\mychart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
        chart2.SaveImage("C:\\New folder\\mychart2.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlApp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is not properly installed!!");
            return;
        }


        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);





        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Date and time Exported :";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = dateandtimelbl.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Exported By :";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = lblemployeeno.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "PartNumber:";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2] = partnumbercomboBox.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3] = "# Materials Type:";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4] = label15.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Part Name:";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 2] = label14.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 5] = "Characterstic:";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 6] = label16.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "Specification:";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 4] = label17.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 7] = "Operation:";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 8] = label18.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 7] = "Period";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 8] = label19.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 9] = "x̅";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 10] = "UCLX";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 11] = "LCLX";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 12] = "Ṝ";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 13] = "UCLR";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 14] = "LCLR";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 9] = label20.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 10] = label21.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 11] = label22.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 12] = label23.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 13] = label24.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 14] = label25.Text;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 2] = "1";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 3] = "2";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 4] = "3";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 5] = "4";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 6] = "5";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 7] = "6";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 8] = "7";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 9] = "8";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 10] = "9";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 11] = "10";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 12] = "11";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 13] = "12";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 14] = "13";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 15] = "14";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 16] = "15";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 17] = "16";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 18] = "17";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 19] = "18";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 20] = "19";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 21] = "20";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 22] = "21";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 23] = "22";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 24] = "23";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 25] = "24";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 26] = "25";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 27] = "26";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 28] = "27";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 29] = "28";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 30] = "29";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 31] = "30";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[64, 32] = "31";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[65, 1] = "Date";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[66, 1] = "Day(D)/Night(N)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[67, 1] = "Top(1)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[68, 1] = "Top(2)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[69, 1] = "Bottom(1)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[70, 1] = "Bottom(2)";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[71, 1] = "X-TOP";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[72, 1] = "X-BOT";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[73, 1] = "X-T/B";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[74, 1] = "Range";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[75, 1] = "Employee no";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[76, 1] = "Date and time";

        xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"C:\\New folder\\mychart.png", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 70, 3600, 400);
        xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(@"C:\\New folder\\mychart2.png", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 50, 500, 3600, 400);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 65, j + 2] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }






        xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.AutoFit();
        xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit();

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("d:\\csharp-Excel.xls", 
   Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, 
   misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, 
    misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);    
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

MessageBox.Show( 
    "Excel file created, you can find the file D:\\csharp-Excel.xls");
```

Is there any way to do something similar to this:

```
//savefile
string saveFileName = "CalendarRubberReport";
SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveDialog.DefaultExt = "xls";
saveDialog.Filter = "ExcelFile|*.xls";
saveDialog.FileName = saveFileName;
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    try
    {
        saveFileName = saveDialog.FileName;

        workbook.Write(ms);
        System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(saveFileName, 
            System.IO.FileMode.Create);
        workbook.Write(file);
        file.Close();
        workbook = null;
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show(saveFileName + " Save Complete", "Complete", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    } catch {
        MessageBox.Show("Error file is open/in use");

    }
} Else {
    workbook = null;
    ms.Close();
    ms.Dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: `saveFileName = saveDialog.FileName;` pass `saveFileName` as the first parameter to `xlWorkBook.SaveAs`.

Comment: Do u mind showing me because i am new to this and i am not sure what you mean so  sorry for that

Comment: @vulcan what do you mean you are new to this? He said pass `saveFileName` as the first parameter to `xlWorkBook.SaveAs()`. That way it will save it at the desired path.

Comment: when i mean new to this is i never do this before my friends ask  me to do something like that so i can save at the location i want

Comment: what is `misvalue` and why do you refer to it to so many times?

Comment: @ashleedawg that's what office is expecting if you don't pass any value. you can't leave it emtpy or null.

Comment: @sLw - my point was that you can save with a new name without displaying a dialog box for the user to interact with.  You can save it wherever you want, with whatever name you want, without any user influence. The VBA method would be [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel). Alternatively  you can set the file attribute to Read Only to prevent overwriting.